# Undefined global variable from response body in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, global-variables, postman

I currently setting up my API testing in `POSTMAN`. 
Faced an issue on parsing and setting up a global variable from response body.

GET response is:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "totalCount": 1,
  "offset": 0,
...
      "siret": "43196025100053",
      "status": "invalid",
...
  }
}
```

In my test, I wrote:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("varSupplier", data["siret"]);
console.log(data["siret"])
```

And console always returns me 'undefined'.
I'm a bit disappointed because I'm able to parse and set global variable from another request. The only difference is that it is a `POST` instead of `GET`. 
It looks logical for me that request type don't impact the variable setting because we are looking at the response body.

Do I miss something ?

Thanks for your help, Regards

Comment: The indentation of your data structure suggests that siret is a property of *something* that is a property of data, and not a property of data itself.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If I understand correctly, I have to indicate the data "path" to siret value. I will take a look later today for that and keep you posted . Regards Quentin

Comment: ok, this solved my issue postman.setEnvironmentVariable("varSupplier", data["suppliers"]["1324059441812734844"]["siret"]